# Efficient zero padding using cudaMemcpy3D

Tags: c++, cuda

I would like to transfer a 3d array stored in linear memory on the host, into a larger (3D) array on the device. As an example (see below), I tried to transfer a (3x3x3) array into a (5x5x3) array.
I expect that on the host I get 2D slices with the following pattern:

```
x x x 0 0
x x x 0 0
x x x 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

where x are the values of my array. However, I get something like that, where `y` are the values of the next 2D slice:

```
x x x 0 0
x x x 0 0
x x x 0 0
y y y 0 0 
y y y 0 0
```

According to the [cudaMemcpy3D documentation](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/2_3/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_gc1372614eb614f4689fbb82b4692d30a.html#gc1372614eb614f4689fbb82b4692d30a) I would have expect that the `extent` parameter would take into account the padding in the vertical axis but apparently not.
Am I mistaken in the understanding of the documentation? If yes, is there any other way to perform this operation? The final size of the array to transfer will be `60x60x900` into an array of size `1100x1500x900`. I use the zero padding to prepare a Fourier transform.

Here is the simplified code that I used:

```
cudaError_t cuda_status;
cudaPitchedPtr d_ptr;
cudaExtent d_extent = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(int)*5,sizeof(int)*5,sizeof(int)*3);
cudaExtent h_extent = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(int)*3,sizeof(int)*3,sizeof(int)*3);

int* h_array = (int*) malloc(27*sizeof(int));
int* h_result = (int*) malloc(512*sizeof(int)*5*3);
for (int i = 0; i<27; i++)
{
    h_array[i] = i;
}
cuda_status = cudaMalloc3D(&d_ptr, d_extent);
cout << cudaGetErrorString(cuda_status) << endl;

cudaMemcpy3DParms myParms = {0};
myParms.extent = h_extent;
myParms.srcPtr.ptr = h_array;
myParms.srcPtr.pitch = 3*sizeof(int);
myParms.srcPtr.xsize = 3*sizeof(int);
myParms.srcPtr.ysize = 3*sizeof(int);
myParms.dstPtr = d_ptr;
myParms.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;

cuda_status = cudaMemcpy3D(&myParms);
cout << cudaGetErrorString(cuda_status) << endl;

cout << "Pitch: " << d_ptr.pitch << " / xsize:" << d_ptr.xsize << " / ysize:" << d_ptr.ysize << endl; // returns Pitch: 512 / xsize:20 / ysize:20 which is as expected

// Copy array to host to be able to print the values - may not be necessary
cout << cudaMemcpy(h_result, (int*) d_ptr.ptr, 512*5*3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) << endl;
cout << h_result[128] << " " << h_result[3*128] << " " << h_result[5*128] << " " << endl; // output : 3 9 15 / expected 3 0 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems here have to do with your extents and sizes.

When an extent is used with cudaMemcpy3D for the non-cudaArray case, it is intended to provide [the size of the region in bytes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gfec7ee5257d48c8528a709ffad48d208).  A way to think about this is that product of the 3 dimensions of the extent should yield the size of the region in bytes.

What you're doing however is scaling each of the 3 dimensions by the element size, which is not correct:

```
cudaExtent h_extent = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(int)*3,sizeof(int)*3,sizeof(int)*3);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                      this is the only element scaling expected
```

You've made a similar error here:

```
myParms.srcPtr.xsize = 3*sizeof(int); // correct
myParms.srcPtr.ysize = 3*sizeof(int); // incorrect
```

We only scale the x (width) dimension by the element size, we don't scale the y (height) or z (depth) dimensions.

I haven't fully verified your code, but with those 2 changes, your code produces the output you indicate is expected:

```
$ cat t1593.cu
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

cudaError_t cuda_status;
cudaPitchedPtr d_ptr;
cudaExtent d_extent = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(int)*5,5,3);
cudaExtent h_extent = make_cudaExtent(sizeof(int)*3,3,3);

int* h_array = (int*) malloc(27*sizeof(int));
int* h_result = (int*) malloc(512*sizeof(int)*5*3);
for (int i = 0; i<27; i++)
{
    h_array[i] = i;
}
cuda_status = cudaMalloc3D(&d_ptr, d_extent);
cout << cudaGetErrorString(cuda_status) << endl;

cudaMemcpy3DParms myParms = {0};
myParms.extent = h_extent;
myParms.srcPtr.ptr = h_array;
myParms.srcPtr.pitch = 3*sizeof(int);
myParms.srcPtr.xsize = 3*sizeof(int);
myParms.srcPtr.ysize = 3;
myParms.dstPtr = d_ptr;
myParms.kind = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;

cuda_status = cudaMemcpy3D(&myParms);
cout << cudaGetErrorString(cuda_status) << endl;

cout << "Pitch: " << d_ptr.pitch << " / xsize:" << d_ptr.xsize << " / ysize:" << d_ptr.ysize << endl; // returns Pitch: 512 / xsize:20 / ysize:20 wich is as expected

// Copy array to host to be able to print the values - may not be necessary
cout << cudaMemcpy(h_result, (int*) d_ptr.ptr, d_ptr.pitch*5*3, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) << endl;
cout << h_result[128] << " " << h_result[3*128] << " " << h_result[5*128] << " " << endl; // output : 3 9 15 / expected 3 0 9

}
$ nvcc -o t1593 t1593.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1593
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
no error
no error
Pitch: 512 / xsize:20 / ysize:5
0
3 0 9
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

I should also point out that the strided memcpy operations in CUDA (e.g. `cudaMemcpy2D`, `cudaMemcpy3D`) are not necessarily the fastest way to conduct such a transfer.  You can find writeups of this characteristic in various questions about `cudaMemcpy2D` here on SO `cuda` tag.

The net of it is that it may be faster to transfer the data to the device in an unstrided, unpadded linear transfer, then write a CUDA kernel to take the data that is now on the device, and place it in the array of interest, with appropriate striding/padding.

Comment: Indeed I was mistaken in the extent. After this fix, it all works. Regarding the unstrided copy and then reformatting in a kernel, shall I consider for example using a kernel that will copy each value of the unstrided array at the correct location of the strided array? Is that the most efficient way to proceed in terms of memory access?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.  Use an ordinary `cudaMemcpy` type operation to copy the unstrided data from host to device.  Then run a kernel on the device that reformats the unstrided data on the device to the proper locations in your desired target array.  Again, there are other questions here on the `cuda` SO tag pertaining to `cudaMemcpy2D` that discuss this concept.